# Set WPF Checkbox value on window draw (not application start)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, checkbox

I have been searching for this for ages now and still have no idea how to achieve it, this is my first C#/WPF application so it is entirely possible that I have seen the answer and just not known it, apologies if it is really easy.

I have a winForms application that launches a WPF window (the winForms is because the app is a system tray icon that spawns other windows). The only WPF window I have currently has two checkboxes that I have managed to store the value of in app.config, that value is also successfully applied to the checkboxes when the application first starts. However I cannot work out how to have the value applied to the checkbox every time the window is opened.

The window is opened by this (with an attempt to fix it commented out):

```
    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var RestartPortal = new RestartPortal();
        //RestartPortal.InvalidateVisual();
        RestartPortal.Show();
    }
```

The values are applied to the window on application run with this (along with another attempt):

```
        public RestartPortal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        alwaysOnTopCheck.InvalidateVisual();
        closeWhenCompleteCheck.InvalidateVisual();
        alwaysOnTopCheck.IsChecked = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("onTopChecked"));
        closeWhenCompleteCheck.IsChecked = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("autoCloseChecked"));
    }
```

If can help out I will be incredibly appreciative.

Thank you.

Edit: In testing I have noticed that the checkboxes seem to be remembering the value that they were assigned when the application first ran, even stranger they force this value into the app.config file each time the window is loaded. To explain better:

1. Run application
2. Load Window
3. Load config in notepad and check that the values correlate
4. (close notepad) Uncheck checkboxes
5. Open config file in notepad again to check that values have been saved correctly.
6. Close window
7. Open window
8. Open config file (again in a fresh notepad) and see that the values correlate and that by opening the window the values have been forced back to the values they held when the application was first run.

To my mind the only way that this can be happening is if somehow something is calling the event handlers for the checkboxes as that is the only place that can save to the app.config file. I am now even more confused than I was before, in case it helps here is the XAML for the checkboxes:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="closeWhenCompleteCheck" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Close when complete" Checked="closeWindow_Checked" Unchecked="closeWindow_Unchecked"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="alwaysOnTopCheck" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Always on top" Checked="onTop_Checked" Unchecked="onTop_Unchecked"/>
```

And here is the c# for the checked and uncheckeds (though only for one checkbox as they are identical):

```
        private void onTop_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Topmost = true;

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["onTopChecked"].Value = (alwaysOnTopCheck.IsChecked).ToString();
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings");
    }

    private void onTop_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Topmost = false;

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        config.AppSettings.Settings["onTopChecked"].Value = (alwaysOnTopCheck.IsChecked).ToString();
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("AppSettings");
    }
```

Any help will be very much appreciated as ever (and probably save my sanity at this point).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try utilizing the Loaded event instead of the constructor.  If your window closes, but the variable storing it does not get destroyed, your constructor will not be called again.

```
public RestartPortal()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Subscribe to the Loaded event
    this.Loaded += RestartPortal_Loaded;
}

void RestartPortal_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Set your values here
    alwaysOnTopCheck.IsChecked = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("onTopChecked"));
    closeWhenCompleteCheck.IsChecked = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("autoCloseChecked"));
}
```

Comment: Hi HoboCannibaL, please see my edit to the original post. I did test your configuration against the original and they both displayed the same behaviour.